# Jackson json xmlgregoriancalendar deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have a problem with parsing json. It has a date for exapmle - "2014-01-07". And when it parses and became to createUserRequest.getBirthday() it contain - "2014-01-07T04:00:00.000+04:00". I need it in createUserRequest object, then I will assert it with another object. **The question is how to get just "2014-01-07"?**

In CreateUserRequest I have XMLGregorianCalendar variable and cannot change it.

> protected XMLGregorianCalendar birthday;

Below just pulled out part of the code. Ignore class and variable names.

```
public class Test {
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    
    public static <T> T parseJson(String pathname, Class<T> objectClass) throws Exception {
        return MAPPER.readValue(new File(pathname), objectClass);
    }

    public void parse() throws Exception {
        CreateUserRequest createUserRequest =
                Test.parseJson("src/test/resources/createUser.json", CreateUserRequest.class);
        System.out.println(createUserRequest.getBirthday());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the methods that `XMLGregorianCalendar` provides?

Answer (score 0):

## `LocalDate`

Your Question is unclear. But if you are asking how to parse a date-only value represented in text as `"2014-01-07"`, the answer is to parse as a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2014-01-07" ) ;
```

The `XMLGregorianCalendar` class represents a moment, a date with time of day as seen in a particular time zone. For a date only value, this is the wrong class to use. Furthermore, this class is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

The latest versions of Jackson support *java.time*.

## Conversion

If handed a [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) object by code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert from that legacy class to the modern *java.time* classes.

Look to new conversion methods added to the old classes.

You need to convert your `XMLGregorianCalendar` object to `ZonedDateTime` by way of `GregorianCalendar`.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = myXmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

A `ZonedDateTime` represent a date with time of day as seen in a particular time zone. But you are interested in only the date portion. So extract a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Compare to your target date with `LocalDate#isEqual`.

```
LocalDate target = LocalDate.parse( "2014-01-07" ) ;
if( ld.isEqual( target ) ) { … }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I should test application with contained XMLGregorianCalendar variable and cannot change it. Then I am using CreateUserRequest and CreateUserResponse classes from this app to assert fields.

Comment: @skva I added a “Conversion” section.